# How to get the svg element id on clicking in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, svg

I'm new to Leaflet and I'm trying to place a SVG file on the Leaflet map. My basic requirement is to get the **svg path id** on clicking in particular SVG element,

I tried making the image overlay on leaflet but I am not able to make that clickable.

```
var imageUrl = 'test2.svg', 
    imageBounds = [(IMAGE BOUNDS)]; 
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code you have tried.

Comment: var imageUrl = 'test2.svg',
        imageBounds = [(IMAGE BOUNDS)];
    L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

Comment: but with image bound i am not able to get the id of clicked element i want to get the id of clicked svg element

Comment: There may not be an 'out-of-the-box' solution using only Leaflet for this requirement.  You will probably need to parse the XML first and then feed the id to your desired output.